# Ant Design Popconfirm - Changing the preselected button to Cancel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

The Popconfirm-modal in Ant Design has the Confirm ("Yes"-)-Button preselected when the modal-window opens.

[image]

Source-code for the modal:

```
import { Popconfirm, message } from 'antd';

function confirm(e) {
  console.log(e);
  message.success('Click on Yes');
}

function cancel(e) {
  console.log(e);
  message.error('Click on No');
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Popconfirm title="Are you sure delete this task?" onConfirm={confirm} onCancel={cancel} okText="Yes" cancelText="No">
    <a href="#">Delete</a>
  </Popconfirm>
, mountNode);
```

Documentation and live-demo here: [Ant Design Documentation](https://ant.design/components/popconfirm/#components-popconfirm-demo-dynamic-trigger)

Is there a way to change the described default-behaviour?

Precisely: 
**Is there a way to define the Cancel (respectively "No"-)-Button as preselected when the Modal appears?**

Comment: What do you mean with "preselected" ? it's preselected to none. do you want to invert the button with primary (blue) color  to the "cancel" button?

Comment: @Kossel Yes. Exactly. I like to have the cancel-button (as the more harmless action) to be blue. And the harmful action NOT highlighted when the window appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get half-way I am afraid.

If you provide an `okType="default"` property, the "Yes" button will no longer have `type="primary"`, and thus look just like the "No" button.

However there is no support for a corresponding `cancelType` property, which means you are not able to make the "No" button blue.

This does feel like a slightly limping API, so you might have success filing a PR implementing `cancelType`. Should be a very simple 3-line patch against https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/popconfirm/index.tsx

Comment: Thanks. You're tip (okType="default") combined with some CSS-selectors, CSS-rules did finally the trick.